# Sobreescritura de returns debido a ciclos en las funciones (Python)

Tags: python, bucles

Tengo una duda, y es que hice un programa que permitiese a un usuario calcular áreas o perímetros de ciertas figuras. La duda que tengo es que yo formulé ciclos para que el usuario pudiese elegir cuantos procesosos podía ejecutar pero queda la posibilidad de que él eliga hacer un proceso dos veces, por lo que no tengo idea de como mostrar los resultados (no tengo la posibilidad de hacer print en la función a ejecutar. Solo return) la solución que plantié fue la siguiente:

```
 def operar():
  x=int(input('Ingrese el número de áreas o perímetros a calcular')
  for i in range(x):
    if i==0:
      operacion=input('Ingrese el nombre de la operación a realizar, los nombres se componen del nombre de la operación a realizar y , ejemplo: "area triangulo" para calcular el área de un triángulo. Después de ingresar todos los datos para todas las operaciones, se procedera a mostrarte los resultados')
    else:
      operacion=input('Ingrese el nombre de la siguiente operación a realizar')
    if operacion=='area cuadrado':
      areaCuadrado
    elif operacion=='perimetro cuadrado':
      perimetroCuadrado
    elif operacion=='area circulo':
      areaCirculo
    elif operacion=='perimetro circulo':
      perimetroCirculo
    elif operacion=='area triangulo':
      perimetroTriangulo
    elif operacion=='perimetro triangulo':
      perimetroCuadrado
    elif operacion=='area rectangulo':
      areaRectangulo
    elif operacion=='perimetro rectangulo':
      perimetroRectangulo
  mostrarResultados(x)

def areaCuadrado():
  operacion='área cuadrado'
  a=float(input('Ingrese el valor de los lados del cuadrado para calcular su área '))
  resultado=a**2
  return resultado, operacion

def perimetroCuadrado():
  operacion='perímetro cuadrado'
  a=float(input('Ingrese el valor de los lados del cuadrado al cual se le va a calcular su perímetro '))
  resultado=a*4
  return resultado, operacion

def areaTriangulo():
  operacion='área triángulo'
  a, b, c=float(input('Ingrese los valores de los tres lado del triángulo al cual se le va a calcular su área '))
  if a>(b+c) or b>(a+c) or c>(a+b):
    print('La figura definida no puede ser un triángulo porque incumple la desigualdad triangular... de todos modos, seguiré trabajando...')
  s=(a+b+c)/2
  areaTAlCuadrado=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)
  resultado=areaTAlCuadrado**(1/2)
  return resultado, operacion

def perimetroTriangulo():
  operacion='perímetro triángulo'
  a, b, c=float(input('Ingrese los valores de tres lado del triángulo al cual se le va a calcular su perímetro '))
  if a>(b+c) or b>(a+c) or c>(a+b):
    print('La figura definida no puede ser un triángulo porque incumple la desigualdad triangular... de todos modos, seguiré trabajando...')
  resultado=a+b+c
  return resultado, operacion

def areaRectangulo():
  operacion='área rectángulo'
  a, b=float('ingrese los valores de los dos lados del rectángulo al cual se le va a calcular su area ')
  resultado=a*b
  return resultado, operacion

def perimetroRectangulo():
  operacion='perímetro rectángulo'
  a, b=float('ingrese los valores de los dos lados del rectángulo al cual se le va a calcular su perimetro ')
  resultado=2*a+2*b
  return resultado, operacion 

def areaCirculo():
  operacion='área círculo'
  pi=3.14159
  radio=float(input('Ingrese el radio del círculo al cual se le va a calcular su área '))
  resultado=pi*radio**2
  return resultado, operacion

def perimetroCirculo():
  operacion='perímetro círculo'
  pi=3.14159
  radio=float(input('Ingrese el radio del círculo al cual se le va a calcular su perimetro '))
  pCirculo=2*pi*radio
  return resultado, operacion

def mostrarResultados(operaciones, resultado, operacion):
  print('A continuación, se van a mostrar los resultados de las operaciones realizadas: ')
  for i in range(operaciones)
    print('El resultado de la operación #', i+1, ' llamada ', operacion, ' es: ' resultado)
  print('Fin del proceso.')

if __name__=='__main__':
  operar()
```

Al ejecutar aparece que tengo un error de sintaxis en la línea 3:

```
File "main.py", line 3
    for i in range(x):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Lo que quiero hacer es por ejemplo: pedir cuántas operaciones hacer, pedir las operaciones a realizar, realizarlas (es posible que se realice una operación más de una vez) y finalmente mostrar los resultados de cada operación (en una función aparte).

Comment: Seguramente el error venía con una lista de llamadas a funciones (_stacktrace_). En la línea 3 se llama a la función `operar`, que llama a la función `mostrarResultados` que tiene un bucle sin terminar. Es mejor que en las preguntas añadas el error completo con el _stacktrace_ para saber dónde tienes el error. Intuyo lo que quieres hacer con el código, pero se me escapa las limitaciones que necesitas hacer. Estaría bien que añadieras un ejemplo de qué esperas que haga el código.

Comment: @chemaCortes gracias por responder. Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: pedir cuantas operaciones quiere realizar el usuario (x), luego pedir las operaciones a realizar  y luego ejecutarlas y mostrar resultados. En mi caso realicé un bucle en función de las operaciones a realizar (x) y comparé el input con varias opciones. A partir de lo que respondió el usuario, se van a ejecutar ciertos programas que van a darme un return. voy a actualizar el código de acuerdo a unas cosas que cambién. me imagino que con el stacktrace te refieres a esto 'File "main.py", line 3'
    'for i in range(x):'

Comment: Hola @ChemaCortes, tenía un montón de problemas, que horror, pero ya pude solucionar mi problema ¿Sería bueno adjuntar el código solucionado?

Comment: Aporta todo lo que creas que pueda ayudar a dar con la solución a tus problemas. Incluso el comentario que detalla cómo esperas que funcione podría ir mejor en la misma pregunta. Piensa siempre que estamos creando información de utilidad para la comunidad. Por _stacktrace_ me refiero a la lista de llamadas que saca el mensaje de error para conocer en qué momento se ha producido el error. Si no lo has visto es porque todavía no es demasiado complejo tu código.

Comment: @JuanFelipeMárquezHernández incluso si has solucionado el error tu mismo, puedes responderte a tu propia pregunta, de hecho StackOverflow invita a los usuarios a hacerlo!

Answer (score 0):

```
def operar():
  x=int(input('Ingrese el número de áreas o perímetros a calcular \n'))
  print('Ingrese el número correspondiente a la operación a realizar: \n 1. Área de un cuadrado \n 2. Perímetro de un cuadrado \n 3. Área de un círculo \n 4. Perímetro de un círculo \n 5. Área de un triángulo \n 6. Perímetro de un triángulo \n 7. Área de un rectángulo \n 8. Perímetro de un rectángulo \n')
  for i in range(x):
    operacion=int(input('Ingrese el número de la operación a realizar: '))
    if operacion==1:
      resultado=areaCuadrado()
      mostrarResultado(resultado)
    elif operacion==2:
      resultado=perimetroCuadrado()
      mostrarResultado(resultado)
    elif operacion==3:
      resultado=areaCirculo()
      mostrarResultado(resultado)
    elif operacion==4:
      resultado=perimetroCirculo()
      mostrarResultado(resultado)
    elif operacion==5:
      resultado=areaTriangulo()
      mostrarResultado(resultado)
    elif operacion==6:
      resultado=perimetroTriangulo()
      mostrarResultado(resultado)
    elif operacion==7:
      resultado=areaRectangulo()
      mostrarResultado(resultado)
    elif operacion==8:
      resultado=perimetroRectangulo()
      mostrarResultado(resultado)
    else:
      print('Instrucción inválida')

def areaCuadrado():
  a=float(input('Ingrese el valor de los lados del cuadrado para calcular su área '))
  resultado=a**2
  return resultado

def perimetroCuadrado():
  a=float(input('Ingrese el valor de los lados del cuadrado al cual se le va a calcular su perímetro '))
  resultado=a*4
  return resultado


def areaTriangulo():
  print('Ingrese los valores de los tres lados del triángulo al cual se le va a calcular su área. \n')
  a=float(input('Lado 1: '))
  b=float(input('Lado 2: ')) 
  c=float(input('Lado 3: '))
  if a>(b+c) or b>(a+c) or c>(a+b):
    print('La figura definida no puede ser un triángulo porque incumple la desigualdad triangular... de todos modos, seguiré trabajando...')
  s=(a+b+c)/2
  areaTAlCuadrado=s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)
  resultado=areaTAlCuadrado**(1/2)
  return resultado

def perimetroTriangulo():
  print('Ingrese los valores de los tres lados del triángulo al cual se le va a calcular su perímetro. \n')
  a=float(input('Lado 1: '))
  b=float(input('Lado 2: ')) 
  c=float(input('Lado 3: '))
  if a>(b+c) or b>(a+c) or c>(a+b):
    print('La figura definida no puede ser un triángulo porque incumple la desigualdad triangular... de todos modos, seguiré trabajando...')
  resultado=a+b+c
  return resultado

def areaRectangulo():
  print('ingrese los valores de los dos lados del rectángulo al cual se le va a calcular su area \n')
  a=float(input('Lado 1: ')) 
  b=float(input('Lado 2: '))
  resultado=a*b
  return resultado

def perimetroRectangulo():
  print('ingrese los valores de los dos lados del rectángulo al cual se le va a calcular su area \n')
  a=float(input('Lado 1: ')) 
  b=float(input('Lado 2: '))
  resultado=2*a+2*b
  return resultado 

def areaCirculo():
  pi=3.14159
  radio=float(input('Ingrese el radio del círculo al cual se le va a calcular su área '))
  resultado=pi*radio**2
  return resultado

def perimetroCirculo():
  pi=3.14159
  radio=float(input('Ingrese el radio del círculo al cual se le va a calcular su perimetro '))
  resultado=2*pi*radio
  return resultado

def mostrarResultado(resultado):
  print('El resultado de la operación realizada es ', resultado, '\n')

if __name__=='__main__':
  operar()
```